# DB_ID function within an IF statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I am trying to enclose a DB_ID function within an IF statement and I'm getting a red squiggly line under the IF please see below for my line of coding, this is in SQL Server:

The Syntax error reads as follows: Syntax error: 'IF' (if) is not valid input at this position

What I'm trying to do is have the script check to see if the database already exists in the system, if it does then it will drop the database. Then the following line outside of the IF statement will create a new database.

I read somewhere that it's because if functions have to be within another function but I'm not sure how to do that and get the same results that I am trying to accomplish.

Any suggestions to why I am getting this error?[image]

Comment: Did you actually run the script and get an error? Maybe InteliSense is suggesting a phantom syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, the DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS corrected the error

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is given below:

```
DROP {DATABASE | SCHEMA} [IF EXISTS] db_name
```

Thus for your database, it should be:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Bookstore;
```

Comment: if you like my answer, pls upvote and/or accept it. thanks.

Comment: Note that `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS` was added to SQL Server 2016, it will not work in SQL server versions before 2016.